# C# Console displaying without ReadKey();

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in coding. I've been reading textbooks and following examples. My question is anyone know why this piece of code I wrote is able to run and not close even though I didn't write Console.Readkey();   ?

```
using System;

namespace StringApp
{
    class StringProg
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "Last night I dreamt of Meghan Riccardelli";

            string substr = str.Substring(23);

            Console.WriteLine(substr);

        // something very funky going on in this example
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: question makes zero sense

Comment: Because Visual Studio will make you a favor and it'll keep it open so you can see its output (when debugger is not attached). Execute it outside VS and it'll flash as you supposed.

Comment: Unable to replicate the described behavior.  This code, as is, writes the string to the console and exits.

Comment: I believe that they are asking WHY this program isn't closing the console window even though it is missing a ReadKey call. I am unable to reproduce this locally, though.

Comment: this code works fine.. perhaps you need to Clean the solution and rebuild.. I cannot reproduce the same problem

Comment: Rebuild your solution.

Comment: also make sure that you don't have any breakpoint enabled on any of the `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to `Debug` -> `Start Without Debugging` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>), the program will run and display `Press any key to continue . . .` until you press a key to exit the console.

If you do `Debug` -> `Start Debugging` (<kbd>F5</kbd>), your program will run and exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your programm to an executable, and open it by double click it will close immediatly after exiting the programm.

If you're within Visual Studio you have to differ between <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Press <kbd>F5</kbd> and the programm will run like an executable. But if you use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> VS will keep the commandline open until you enter a key.

Comment: Jonesopolis did just write the same thing as I did..

Comment: @MethodMan Apart from a possible _not-English-as-first-language_ problem, I see nothing wrong with this answer.  Essentially the same as Jonesopolis's answer

Comment: his answer gives a better visual so I will give you the +1 since you are pouting ...lol

Comment: Thanks Micky! I'm currently reading through the styling guid / -help, so next time it will be better ;)

Comment: Not a problem good sir :)

Comment: I wasn't using VS. However, thanks guys I figured out the answer to the question. It was simple I am an idiot.